# Rails - server stripping whitespace from params when not intended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

Question as above - I have a form input:

```
<%= f.input :ticket_book_number,
label: "<abbr title='required'>*</abbr> Ticket book number".html_safe,
input_html: { data: { behaviour: 'check-ticket-book-number', url: verify_booking_system_ticket_books_path, agent: resource.agent.id },
error: 'asd' } %>
```

When I enter a ticket number of '12345 ' with a space at the end, and stick a binding.pry in my controller action, my params come through as:

```
Parameters: {"agent"=>"352", "ticket"=>"12345"}
```

Is there any way I can specify in the input to include whitespace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show the "`simple_form_for`" line? I think the params should be nested

Answer (score 7):

Looks seems you have `ticket_book_number` as `integer` in database. `form_for` or `simple_form` automatically detect field type and created input for this type with further processing. If it's true, and you need to save whitespaces, you have to re-create `ticket_book_number` field as `string`.

Comment: Thanks but ticket_book_number is a string

Comment: @Mark can you add html code, which was generate in browser for this input? Try to add `as: :string` or `as: :text` options to f.input and resend info.